# Retrieving Raw Data From RSS Feeds

Tags: xml, rss, feed

I am trying to retrieve and use the raw data from RSS feeds.  For example, trying to take a Yahoo Live Sports Scores RSS feed and taking the information and storing it in a database or displaying it on my web page for the games at interest.  What is the best way to do this?  I would prefer to use PHP to do this.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Magpie RSS for PHP. You can get if from SourceForge.net